# DataTable Not Refreshing on AJAX Update Success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have the following for updating a DataTable. Its updating my database just fine but onSuccess in AJAX it does not refresh the table. I use on success: `$('#data-table').html(data);` but its not working correctly. Any advice is welcome, thank you in advance!

I use DataTables from the site: https://datatables.net/.

**My PHP:**

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "table");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $output = '';
    $message = '';
    $numeclub = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["numeclub"]);
    $coregraf = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["coregraf"]);
    $numeformatie = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["numeformatie"]);
    $disciplina = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["disciplina"]);
    $categorievarsta = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["categorievarsta"]);
    $sectiuni = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["sectiuni"]);
    $numecoregrafie = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["numecoregrafie"]);

    if ($_POST["id"] != '') {
        $query = "UPDATE momente SET numeclub='$numeclub', coregraf='$coregraf', 
          numeformatie='$numeformatie', disciplina = '$disciplina', 
          categorievarsta = '$categorievarsta', sectiuni = '$sectiuni', 
          numecoregrafie = '$numecoregrafie' WHERE id='" . $_POST["id"] . "'";
        $message = 'Data Updated';
    }

    if (mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
        $output .= '<label class="alert alert-success">' . $message . '</label>';
        $select_query = "SELECT * FROM momente ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $select_query);
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

Here's the AJAX code that is working fine but on success does not refresh my DataTable...

```
$('#insert_form').on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: $('#insert_form').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#insert').val("Introduc datele");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
            $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');

            $('#data-table').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Call the datatable once again after html(data)

Comment: $('#myTable').DataTable();

Comment: nope, it does not work, it pulls out the whole table

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, You are outputting the $output and not the $result which is supposed to be the result of the query. And console.log(data) in the success function to see what you get back.

Comment: in the console i get : <label class="alert alert-success">Data Updated</label>

Comment: "*..but onSuccess in AJAX it does not refresh the table*" how do you expect this to happen...? What do you believe should happen automagically after `$('#data-table').html(data);` ...?